# When to instantiate a new class inside my controller and when to inject that class as a dependency?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, instantiation

When do I use `new` to create any class inside my controllers, and when do I *inject* the class into my controller?

For example, say I have an `AnnotationBuilder` class (it builds a `Zend\Form` object by reading annotations inside a domain entity).

I can call it inside my controller like so:

```
$form = (new AnnotationBuilder())->createForm(MyForm::class);
```

or I can pass an instance of `AnnotationBuilder` into my controller and call it like this:

```
$form = $this->annotationBuilder->createForm(MyForm::class);
```

or if I pass `AnnotationBuilder` directly to the method, I can use:

```
$form = $annotationBuilder->createForm(MyForm::class);
```

Are there any guidelines to this?  For example, reading about dependency injections I can venture out to guess that any and all of my dependencies must be stated, and since `AnnotationBuilder` is a part required to build the form, I can probably inject it into the constructor of my controller.  Or as a setter method.

What about any other class?  Currently in my existing controller I can count about 6 `new` operators.  Do I blindly refactor them to all be passed into the controller?

Is it ever acceptable to just create something using `new` inside a controller?

Comment: Passing instances into a class allows you to test your class better, allowing you to create mocks of classes where you can't directly test.

Comment: I'd consider `new` acceptable for value objects. As a side note, never refactor blindly, unless you have 300% test coverage. e.g. objects are passed by reference, and you may experience some dirty states if your container reuse the same object in multiple invocations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complex your model layer is. In case of `AnnotationBuilder`, I would definitely pass it as a dependency, though, not necessarily in a controller. I am not a Zend user and have no idea what it actually does, but this sounds like "output stuff", which should go in View instances (if you have those and not just dumb templates).

In general, I would have code, where controller's only interact with various services from the model layer. And since those services would be singular per runtime, it is better to pass them as a dependency.

But inside each service I would juggle variety of entities (domain objects). And, while there is only one `Authentication` service per runtime, in it would probably be managed multiple `Identity` (or maybe `Account`) entities. These "repeated instance" I would **not** pass as a dependency. Instead I would either use `new` operator or create them using some factory (which would be a dependency, for unit-testing purposes).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Zend\Form kind of covers everything -> I construct the form using AnnotationBuilder (which uses my domain object to create the form object itself), then populate the form with values (sometimes pulling those from database), then I pass the completed form to the View, and view takes care about rendering it into HTML.

Comment: In other words, AnnotationBuilder is a transient object.  It is used to build something and is then discarded.  It's like a Factory of sorts.  I could move it out of controller entirely and build the form some other place, and then inject the form into controller...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good ideia to just follow a rule because someone said so. It's important to have a reason to do it.

What's the matter between injecting something and instatiating it?

The scenario where i find it to matter more, is in unit tests. You unit test your controllers? If yes, the `AnnotationBuilder` is something you want to mock, because it hits performance or for other reason?

Besides the testing cases, it's a problem to have this concrete dependency, or you should inject an abstraction of it? For this last one, in general, i don't see the problem of the controller depending on concretes because it's just an infrastructure entry point to your application.